# Position: fixed not working in chrome no matter what

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, fixed

I currently have a navigation AND a slide down Social menu in Sass which both are fixed.

Yet when I scroll down nothing happens in Chrome. In Safari it does work.

I googled many times and even when I use

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

it still doesn't work.

Here is the css code for my social menu (it has a ul and a li in it)

```
.social-menu{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:10000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    background-color:rgba(123, 123, 123, 0.86);

    .social-list{
        width:50%;
        margin:0 auto;
        .social-list-item{
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my JSFiddle, my social menu is nested in my body. Here it works, maybe try it out for yourself in chrome?

Also, I make use of `<!DOCTYPE html>`

http://jsfiddle.net/777t4twf/7/

Comment: it looks fixed! check your fiddle..! its working even on my machine

Comment: set the body margin to 0 in your css

Comment: @Deepak I know, I mentioned that it works in my fiddle. But on my website it doesnt :(.

Comment: @AndrewBone I already have a margin and padding of 0 set on my body..

Comment: @FabianTjoeAOn Then provide a link to your website.

Comment: why top:0 AND bottom:0???

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez top and bottom work fine together. You mean, why top, bottom AND height, surely.

Comment: top and bottom it's a technique to center an element vertically when a fixed height which I don't think it's the case here, and it's needs margin:auto which he is not using... that's why I asked why.

Comment: @MrLister Alright, I threw it online on my test server http://beta.chu-on.com/

Comment: have you given `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to your body tag?or is it getting added on page load?

Comment: @DeepakYadav It's on my nav bar, tried adding it to the body tag but it also doesn't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the `transform-style: preserve-3d` from the `body` and the `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` from the `.container` it works. Try it in your [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

I assume that these transforms are (quite rightly) affecting the position of the nav in the z axis.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; */
    /* transform-style: preserve-3d; */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    /* -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); */
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot man, it finally works. Preserve 3d was the culprit!

Answer (score 1):

Try giving "transform: inherit" in your container of "social-menu".
I tried this and its working for me, as my container element in chrome was adding "transform: none" in computed css of dev tools.